# Pick Date from Jquery Calender and Check it WIth DB and Print it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Have a calender and stored the selected date in variable "x", i want to pass that date and check with database and display the events on that date..

```
    enter code here<div id="calendar"></div>
Date:<input type="text" id="datepicker_send" name="datepicker_send" readonly="readonly"   >                 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script src="/jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script>  var x='';
    $('#calendar').datepicker({

    altField: '#datepicker_send',

        inline: true,

        firstDay: 1,

        showOtherMonths: true,

        altFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",

        dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",

        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

         onSelect: function(dateText){
         $('#event-date').text(dateText)
          x=dateText;          
         // alert(x);
         $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
         url: 'check_events.php', 
         data: {dateText: x }, 
         success: function(data)
         { (" I want to get the result and store in an some ID so that i can display the results with <span><id></span>); }
              } );
        }
        }
    </script>
```

**check_events.php:-**

```
    enter code here<?php mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['dateText']))

{

$x = $_POST['dateText'];

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM events WHERE date='$x'");

while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_check))

{

print_r($res);

}

}
?>
```

Please help the needful ... thanks

Comment: what is the date format you are posting?

Comment: Same Format yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: ajax request successful?

Comment: instead of post try with `$_REQUEST`

Comment: ok... and what to use in ajax succes mesage... how to retrive the output of php file into ajax call to print it...

Comment: instead of `print_r($res)` use `echo json_encode($res)` you will get it in `data`.

Comment: yes did 
   data: {dateText: x }, 
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data)
   { alert("data"); }
     } );
  }
  });   but it is showing as error...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying enter date in wrong format to the `mysql`. So you need to convert date into the supporting format.

```
mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['dateText']))

{

$x = date_format($_POST['dateText'],'Y-m-d'); // convert date into mysql format

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM events WHERE date='$x'");

while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_check))

{

print_r($res);

}

}
?>
```

// in script you are missed `"` in ajax code

```
<script>  
var x='';
$('#calendar').datepicker({

altField: '#datepicker_send',

    inline: true,

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    altFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",

    dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",

    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

     onSelect: function(dateText){
     $('#event-date').text(dateText)
      x=dateText;          
     // alert(x);
     $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
     url: 'check_events.php', 
     data: {dateText: x }, 
     success: function(data)
     { (" I want to get the result and store in an some ID so that i can display the results with <span><id></span>"); } // here you miss the quotes
          } );
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: u dint understood my question ... there i want to display the result of $res code from check_events.php..... through Json onSelect: function(dateText){
   $('#event-date').text(dateText)
          x=dateText;          
         // alert(x);
   $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
   url: 'check_events.php', 
   data: {dateText: x }, 
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data)
   { alert("data"); }
     } );
  }
  });
 </script>